# Coefficient Thresholding by keeping largest coefficients

Tags: matlab

I have been doing some experimentations using some transformation e.g DCT on image data in Matlab.
example in DCT using 512x512 px lena image:

x = double(imread('lenna.bmp'));
R = dct2(x);

Then, i want to threshold the transform coefficients by keeping 100000 largest coefficients of R and set the remaining to zeros.

How can i do that?

Comment: i've tried using global thresholding sqrt(2*log(number.of coefficient)

Comment: It's global thresholding you want. Try building an inverse histogram and then you can find which value splits your sample between the 100.000 larger coeffficients and the rest. Use this value to threshold.

Comment: What is the formula `sqrt(2*log(number.of coefficient))` expected to provide? What is the number of coefficient? Note that this is the same as `(number.of coefficient)`, right? The 2*log(x) = log(x^2).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`prctile`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/prctile.html) to find the value that is exceeded or equalled by exactly 100000 entries of `R`. Then use that value as a threshold, that is, set all lower values to zero:

```
threshold = prctile(R(:),(1-1e5/numel(R))*100); %// compute threshold
R(R<threshold) = 0; %// set values below the threshold to zero
```